# set OnClick function to a list of <ul>, the last ul is erase the first ul-s

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

Im trying to create list of UL views, and add them a specific onclick function.
this is my code:

```
function createList(divName) {

  var divName = document.getElementById(divName);
  for (var i in myListOfObjects) {
    // create an arbitrary ul element
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    var s = myListOfObjects[i]; //get specific object (JSON object)
    var subject = document.createElement('li'),
      subjectContent = document.createTextNode("someText"); // subject
    subject.appendChild(subjectContent);
    ul.appendChild(subject);
    ul.onclick = function() {
      //pass  the specific TEXT from the specific JSON object to the next page.
      window.location.href = "NewPage.html" +
        "?specificText=" + JSON.stringify(s["TEXT"]);
    };
    // append the created ul element above to the  div element                
    div.appendChild(ul);
  }

}
```

My problem is :
When I run the function , click fucntion Get the same " TEXT " for all objects in  " MyListOfObjects " ( the text is the last object "s" ) , I checked the text value in this list is not the same , so how can I know what is causing the problem foreign this ? And how to solve this problem .

Thanks !

Comment: paste your HTML as well. what is `myListOfObjects`?

Comment: its list of objects that I want to get the specific TEXT field from All of them.

Comment: Not to be that guy, but English lessons would be a good idea if you want to learn code.

Comment: @coderap the object is a JSON object, how can I get the specific object if i didnt put it in the ul item? in the ul item i put only the text field but the object has more fields that i want to show in the next page, but to the next page only the last object send, its not care wich item clicked the next page got allways the last object... (sorry about my English...)

Comment: someone? can help me?

Answer (score 0):

the object is a JSON object, how can I get the specific object if i didnt put it in the ul item? in the ul item i put only the text field but the object has more fields that i want to show in the next page, but to the next page only the last object send, its not care wich item clicked the next page got allways the last  object... (sorry about my English...)